# Find command with regex

Tags: find, regular-expression

File I want to find.

```
20200521-285353-rpi3-4497-00-0-13-0-0-0-0-n.jpg
Files with Date in the filename from 2020-01-01 to 2020-09-31
```

not

```
20201021-*.*
```

My regex string:

```
^20200[0-9][0-3][0-9]-[0-2].*
```

Find version: find (GNU findutils) 4.7.0-git

I can't find a combination that works.
My attempts:

```
find . -type f -regextype grep -regex '20200[1-9]-*.*'
```

```
find . -type f -regex '^20200[0-9][0-9][0-9]\-[0-2].*'
```

```
find . -type f -regextype sed -regex '^20200[0-9][0-9][0-9]\-[0-2].*'
```

Comment: Probably the most important thing to note is that `-regex` is a *whole path match*. So for example your second attempt would match if you replaced `^` at the start with `.*/` (although the escaping of `-` is not necessary). This behavior is different from that of `-name` which (as well as being a glob match rather than a regex) matches against the file name only.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and clarify what should be found and what should not be found. Should `￼20200521.txt` be found? How about `2020071128847297923497432-4234y9234-foo-bar`? We need to know the exact parameters to help you.

Comment: The escaping of " - " is  Not from me, a User put it in my String.

Comment: ThomasDr the `\-` was in your [original version](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/616193/revisions). If you feel your question has been edited wrongly, please do [fix it](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/616193/edit)

Answer (score 3):

Use a glob and keep it simple

```
find -type f -name '20200521-*'
```

Answer (score 2):

If  you  want  to  find  only  `20200521-285353-rpi3-4497-00-0-13-0-0-0-0-n.jpg`, use

```
find . -type f -name 20200521-285353-rpi3-4497-00-0-13-0-0-0-0-n.jpg
```

If you want to find files whose names look like

```
YYYYMMDD-
```

followed by

```
         0, 1 or 2
```

followed by

```
                  (something)
```

where *`YYYY`* is `2020`, use

```
find . -type f -name '2020[01][0-9][0-3][0-9]-[0-2]*'
```

but be aware that it will match false positives
like `0231` (February 31), `0400` (April 0), `1038` (October 38)
and `1701` (the first day of the 17th month). 
If you want to find files whose names look like the above,
but only for January (`01`) through September (`09`),
excluding October, November and December (`10`, `11` and `12`), use

```
find . -type f -name '20200[0-9][0-3][0-9]-[0-2]*'
```

Note that the above all end with **`*`** and *not* **`.*`**.

Please edit your question to clarify what you want to find.

And by the way, what is `285353`? 
It isn’t a valid *`HHMMSS`*.